# PHP Regex for checking space or certain characters after string

Tags: php, regex, string

I need a regex which can basically check for space, line break etc after string.

So conditions are,

1. Allow special characters **`.`**, **`_`**, **`-`**, **`+`** inside the string i.e.`@hello.world`, `@hello_world`, `@helloworld`, etc.
2. Discard anything including special characters where there is no alpha-numeric string after them i.e. `@helloworld.<space>`, `@helloworld-<space>`, `@helloworld.?`, etc. must be parsed as `@helloworld`

My existing RegEx is `/@([A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+)/` which works perfectly **Condition #1**, but still there seems to be a problem **Condition #2**

I am using above RegEx in `preg_replace()`

**Solution**:

```
$str = preg_replace('#@[\w+.\-]+\b#', '[[$0]]', $str);
```

This works perfectly.

Tested with

> http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to easily find the position between an alphanumeric letter and a non-alphanumeric letter:

```
$str = preg_replace('#@[\w+.\-]+\b#', '[[$0]]', $str);
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/0ShCm

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

1. Use [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) to reverse the string
2. Use [`strcspn`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) to find the longest prefix of the reversed string that does not contain any alphanumeric characters
3. Cut the prefix off with [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
4. Reverse the string again; this is your final result

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/rnHfV)**.

I 'm not taking into account any requirement that restricts the legal characters in the string to some subset, but you can use your regular expression for that (or even `strspn`, which might be faster).

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me but I needed an exact solution which @kobi has provided.

Comment: @whoru: That code won't work as you describe if I get the description correctly though. Try it with the input `@helloworld_`. Word of advice: don't use a solution you don't completely understand.

Comment: I needed `@helloworld_` to be accepted because `@helloworld_` in retrived from something like `helloworld_@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because it's reading the string as a whole. If you want it to parse out everything after the alphanumeric section you might have to do like and end(explode()); and run that through to make sure that it isn't valid and if it isn't valid then remove it from the equation, but then you'd have to check the end for every possible explode point i.e. .,-,~,etc.

Then again another trap that you might run into is that in the case of a  item or anything w/ alphanumeric value it might just parse everything from after the last alphanumeric character on.

Sorry that this isn't much help, but I figured thinking aloud does help.